# "The C compiler identification is unknown" Windows 10 - OpenHMD

Tags: visual-studio-2012, cmake

I am trying to setup OpenHMD, and when I run cmake I get following output:

```
c:\OpenHMD>cmake . -G "Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64"
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/OpenHMD/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/OpenHMD/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".`
```

What is my problem?

I running Windows 10
I have updated to Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 (KB2781514)

Comment: Becearfull to use the right version number
You need to open VS studio command prompt `> cd c:\OpenHMD`
    `> rm CMakeLists`
    `> cmake . -G "Visual Studio 11 2012 Win64"`

Comment: Probably you don't have the correct Windows SDK installed. But check `CMakeError.log` for more details.